# Problems when writing in SublimeText3

Tags: python, c#, sublimetext3

I used Visual Studio (VS) community as my first IDE. However, I did not like how slow it was. So I switched to Sublime Text. It is very fast. But, the two problems are when writing in python, the autocomplete feature does not work, (sometimes it does and sometimes doesn't) and the second problem is when writing in C# `Console.Write("hello world");`, it recognises this line (or any line) as normal text even though I have saved it as a C# file.

Please provide any help or suggestion in the comments section, thanks!

Comment: bottom right corner you can change the syntax highlighting to specific languages

Comment: can you clarify on *autocomplete does not work*?  my understanding, and I use ST3 is that ST doesn't really do smart type autocomplete like Intellisense.  instead of knowing that say `foo = []` means `foo.append(` because foo is a list, it will propose existing tokens in the current text.  so it might propose `foo` and then it might propose an existing method names that are *already* in your text.  it won't magically say "ah foo is a list, therefore dropbox w names of list attributes/methods.  what are your expectations?

Comment: personally, I care little for intellisense, having for example struggled with turning it off on MS SQL Visual SQL editor for a database with 15K+ tables where it made everything crawl while I typically knew the column names of the subset I was working with.  so I am good w ST3.  but I get that not everyone thinks like me.  also, there may be plugins for ST when Python code is annotated w type hints.  I use mypy but haven't  bothered w tracking down a ST3 plugin for it.